# Trying to "pay what I want" for Vocal in the Appcenter

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I want to buy Vocal in the Appcenter, since in principle I'd like to support developers making good apps for Elementary.

But I can't get Appcenter to accept my payment details. I think the problem is the card expiry field?  It prompts with "MM / YY" but will only accept 4 characters.  I put in 0618 but the "Pay" button remains greyed out.

Ideas?

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the expiry date field only accepts 4 digits, but it should work that way (I already bought Vocal and Nimbus and didn't encounter your issue). 
Check the other fields for things like missing digit in CC number etc.

Comment: Definitely right.  Perhaps the credit card number authentication is wrong and doesn't understand non-US numbers properly?